# Javascript - Month Year range automatically on selectlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, dynamic

I'm try to automacially create a select list that has the following:

```
<select name="Range" id="ranges">
  <option value="July 2017">July 2017</option>
   <option value="June 2017">June 2017</option>
     <option value="May 2017">May 2017</option>
```

**all the way down to August 2015**

```
     <option value="August 2015">August 2015</option>

</select>
```

The first option must be the current Month and Year

is this possible to be automatically populated via javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get an array of months between now and `Aug 1, 2015` and then use that array to make options in select, something like this:

```js
function dateRange(startDate, endDate) {
  var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
  ];
  var startMonth = parseInt(startDate.getMonth());
  var endMonth   = parseInt(endDate.getMonth());
  var startYear  = parseInt(startDate.getFullYear());
  var endYear    = parseInt(endDate.getFullYear());
  var dates      = [];
  for (var i = startMonth; i >= 0; i--)
     dates.push(monthNames[i] + " " + startYear);
  startYear--; 
 for(var i = startYear; i > endYear; i--) {
   for (var j = monthNames.length-1; j >= 0; j--)
  dates.push(monthNames[j] + " " + i);
 }

  for (var i = monthNames.length-1; i >= endMonth; i--)
 dates.push(monthNames[i] + " " + endYear);
  return dates;
}
dates = dateRange(new Date(), new Date('August 1, 2015'));
var select = document.getElementById('datepicker');
dates.forEach(function(d){
 select.options.add(new Option(d, d));
});
```

```html
    <select id="datepicker"></select>
```

Comment: it works!..BUT! i need to hide the months that havent happened yet in 2017

Comment: @memaxt fixed it, check now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated solution to your requirement, with just plain JQuery and no datepicker:

```js
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
var currentMonthName = months[new Date().getMonth() + 1];

for (i = new Date().getFullYear(); i > 2014; i--) {
  $.each(months, function(index, value) {
    if (i == 2015 && value == 'Sep')
      return false;

    if (i == new Date().getFullYear()) {
      if (value == currentMonthName) {
        return false;
      } else {
        $('#yearMonthInput').append($('<option />').val(index + "_" + i).html(value + " " + i));
      }
    } else {
      $('#yearMonthInput').append($('<option />').val(index + "_" + i).html(value + " " + i));
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="yearMonthInput"></select>
```

Comment: it works!..BUT! i need to hide the months that havent happened yet in 2017

Comment: wahoo!..thank you! both jquery and javascript work just as intended!...thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

My code, maybe it`s not very small and beautiful, but...)

```js
let date = new Date();
let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

let currentYear = date.getFullYear();
let currentMonth = date.getMonth();

let lastYear = date.getFullYear() - 2;
let lastMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;

let objectOfDates = [];

for (let j = 0; j < months.length; j++) {
    objectOfDates.unshift(`${months[j]} ${currentYear - 1}`);
};

for (let i = 0; i <= currentMonth; i++) {
    objectOfDates.unshift(`${months[i]} ${currentYear}`);
};

for (let k = 11; k >= lastMonth; k--) {
    objectOfDates.push(`${months[k]} ${currentYear - 2}`);
};

let select = document.querySelector('select[name="Range"]');

objectOfDates.forEach(function(value){
    select.options.add(new Option(value, value));
});
```

```html
<select name="Range" id="ranges">
</select>
```